# App for removing instagram followers quickly

Tags: instagram

To reset my relationship with social media, I'm trying to delete most of my Instagram followers and following, going from roughly 1000 in each category to maybe 100.

I've tried to do this one by one in the web app. But soon I got a `429 error of too many requests` and it stopped processing my unfollows.

Are there any third-party apps that can help with this?

Comment: I think an app would see the same error.  You just need to slow down.